# NetworkServerControl has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Netbeans to develop a Java application using also JavaFX.

While developing the app, I took the BAD decision to upgrade my environment and went from Java8 to Java 11 and from Derby 10.14 to derby 10.15. The result was that I understood that the JavaFX support in the new environment was too complex for me and I downgraded my environment again to Java8 and Derby 10.14.

Now though, when I try to start the Java DB server, i get the following error: "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/derby/drda/NetworkServerControl has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0"

I have searched google, stackoverflow, etc. without any result.
Sure, I understand that this is a problem of different versions, but How I can bring NetworkServerControl back to the vrsion I am using? Obviously, I do not want to upgrade to Java9.

Comment: Answer: The problem was in the Java DB properties. This too had to be downgraded. Just for anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the Java DB properties. This too had to be downgraded. Just for anyone with the same problem. Right-click on Derby DB, properties, change link to downgraded Derby installation folder .