# Unable to compile Java after a reinstall of Visual Studio Code: “ NameOfMyClass has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime”

Tags: windows, java, visual-studio-code

Have reinstalled Windows for my laptop and reinstalled Visual Studio Code, JDK as well. But am facing a debugger(?) problem.

Everytime when I'm trying to compile/debug Java file outside of Maven getting this exception (even if this is empty class with simple console output "Hello world" written by me I get this error. Trying to compile/debug using Java Extension Pack: :

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: NameOfMyClass has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 52.65535), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

- JDK version is 1.8.0 201
- VS Code 1.32.3
- JAVA_HOME variable is set to right path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201"

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1417843/networkservercontrol-has-been-compiled-by-a-more-recent-version-of-the-java-runt

Comment: @Ramhound Highly unlikely to be related; the error itself is very generic and none of the other symptoms match (different programs, different libraries, the answer to that question relates to a lib that's not even used here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is connected with Java Debugger extension. I had the same problem and it has been logged in issue log: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/555

Problem is only with single file applications like HelloWorld. It is ok if you run maven project.

Medsonk's instruction worked for me: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/555#issuecomment-478464496

> *summary:
>
>   1. make sure uninstall jdk8 clean
>
>   2. install jdk11
>
>   3. add "vmArgs": "--enable-preview" in launch.json
>
>   4. F1, "Java: Clean ……" and "Java: Force ……"
>
>   5. run standalone file again*